# Impersonation causing unhandled exception

Tags: c#, xaf

I have a C# windows application that I need to impersonate a userid other than the one that the user logged on with when I access files on a file share.  I use impersonation to switch to this user and then switch back.  I also need to revert back to the logged on user to access local files.  I get a System.ExecutionEngineException that is not being caught by the application and it just stops.  Here is the code.  Any ideas why I am getting this error or suggestions on how to do it better.

Edit: The application is using the XAF framework by DevExpress.

```
public static class Impersonation
{
    #region Fields
    public static WindowsImpersonationContext newUser;
    public static string domain;
    public static string userName;
    public static string password;
    #endregion
    // group type enum
    private enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL : int
    {
        SecurityAnonymous = 0,
        SecurityIdentification = 1,
        SecurityImpersonation = 2,
        SecurityDelegation = 3
    }
    // obtains user token
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool LogonUser(string pszUsername, string pszDomain, string pszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

    // closes open handes returned by LogonUser
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    // creates duplicate token handle
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private extern static bool DuplicateToken(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle, int SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL, ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);

    #region Methods
    public static void RevertUser()
    {
        newUser.Undo();
    }
    #region ImpersonateApexApplicationUser
    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to impersonate a user.  If successful, returns 
    /// a WindowsImpersonationContext of the new users identity.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sUsername">Username you want to impersonate</param>
    /// <param name="sDomain">Logon domain</param>
    /// <param name="sPassword">User's password to logon with</param></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static void ImpersonateApexApplicationUser()
    {
        // initialize tokens
        IntPtr pExistingTokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);
        IntPtr pDuplicateTokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);
        pExistingTokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        pDuplicateTokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
            const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;

            if (!LogonUser(userName, domain, Encryption.Decrypt(password), LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref pExistingTokenHandle))
                throw new Exception(string.Format("LogonUser() failed with error code {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
            else
                if (!DuplicateToken(pExistingTokenHandle, (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, ref pDuplicateTokenHandle))
                {
                    int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    CloseHandle(pExistingTokenHandle); // close existing handle
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("DuplicateToken() failed with error code: {0}", errorCode));
                }
                else
                {
                    // create new identity using new primary token
                    WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(pDuplicateTokenHandle);
                    newUser = newId.Impersonate();
                }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            // close handle(s)
            if (pExistingTokenHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(pExistingTokenHandle);
            if (pDuplicateTokenHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(pDuplicateTokenHandle);
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

I call it like this once at the beginning of the program:

```
    Impersonation.domain = "xxxx";
    Impersonation.userName = "xxxx;
    Impersonation.password = "xxxx";
    Impersonation.ImpersonateApexApplicationUser();
```

and then:

```
Impersonation.ImpersonateApexApplicationUser(); 
//file share access code
Impersonation.RevertUser();
```

Comment: At what line/call in your `ImpersonateApexApplicationUser()` method is the exception being thrown if you step through it? Or is it being thrown in `RevertUser`?

Comment: I cannot tell where the exception is being thrown because it is not caught by any of my exception handling. It is not in the Impersonation class or any of it's methods.

Comment: Have you added the main user which your process is running to local security policies, Act as part of the Operating System?

Comment: I do not have a problem with the logon user having rights to the files.